# Transparent vertex colort hreejs

Tags: three.js

I have boxGeometry with 2 vertexes. Is it possible, that one of the vertex is transparent?
How do i do that?

Desired result

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 0):

You can have vertex colors with an alpha channel (see [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/transparent-vertex-colors-in-bufferattribute/16317/7) and [example](https://twitter.com/onirenaud/status/1377260813543563264)), but I don't think it would produce the sharp diagonal boundary you show. It may be more appropriate to make a `BufferGeometry` in the shape of the pink region.